# Exclude a file from build in .Net Core project

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-core

I have some files that are specific to either .Net Core or .Net proper.

I could place a conditional compilation `#if` around the entire, say, class but is it possible to exclude/include a file conditionally in the `csproj` file?

I have tried this (to no avail):

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compiled Remove="IDbProviderFactories.cs" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'netstandard2.0' and '$(TargetFramework)' != 'netcoreapp2.0'"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The item type is `Compile`, you used `Compiled` (extra `d`) in your code. If you change this, your example should work.